# Почему функцию с setTimeout нужно обозначить после document.ready?

Tags: jquery

В книге Head Fisrst Jquery есть задание, где нужно сделать регулярное появление и исчезновение элемента в определенном интервале. function lightning_one()

Вопрос. Если определить функцию внутри document.ready - setTimeout перестает работать - пишет, что переменная lightning_one() не определена.

Если же определить функцию после document.ready. Все начинает работать.

Почему так?

Вставляю кусок кода скрином из книги.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подавайте ссылку на функцию, а не строку, первым параметром в `setTimeout`. Когда параметр - строка, она выполняется в глобальной области видимости, где `lightning_one` не видна, если она объявлена внутри `$(document).ready`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  lightning_one();

  function lightning_one() {
    console.log("lightning_one");
    setTimeout(lightning_one, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Все понятно. Спасибо